# Join columns of SQL queries together

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got the below two queries which I'm trying to figure out if I can merge into a single query.  Both tables have the exact same three columns, but the organization names will differ between the two in many cases.  The queries are like so:

```sql
SELECT OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, COUNT(*) AS Complete
FROM #complete c
JOIN #wanted w ON w.WorkerKey = c.WorkerKey
GROUP BY OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm
ORDER BY 1;

SELECT OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, COUNT(*) AS Wanted
FROM #wanted 
GROUP BY OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm
ORDER BY 1;
```

So the first one might end up with something like this:

```
OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm | Complete  
------------------------------------------------
Foo                                   |   2  
Bar                                   |  17
```

and then the second would would be

```
OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm | Wanted
------------------------------------------------
Foo                                   |   27  
Baz                                   |  132
```

So in the resulting query I'd want:

```
OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm | Wanted | Complete
---------------------------------------------------------
Foo                                   |   27   |   2
Bar                                   |    0   |  17
Baz                                   |  132   |   0
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, 
  Count(w.WorkerKey) as wanted, 
  COUNT(c.WorkerKey) AS Complete
FROM #wanted w
LEFT JOIN #complete c ON w.WorkerKey = c.WorkerKey
GROUP BY OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: So nice and clean!

Comment: Just a note: I think you should indicate which table the colum `OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm` is coming from with a prefix. Maybe `c.`, maybe `w.`.

Comment: Actually. is this query good? Shouldn't it use an `OUTER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`? As it is, it's probably missing either `Bar` or `Baz` (or both).

Comment: @Impaler, LEFT JOIN is an OUTER JOIN (you can write it as LEFT OUTER JOIN if you like). And the Join might be instead a FULL OUTER JOIN, he knows the underlying data best. In his sample query it looked like outputs were incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
select OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, sum(Wanted), sum(Complete)
from ( (select OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, 1 as Wanted , 0 as Complete
        from #wanted w
       ) union all
       (select OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, 0 as Wanted , 1 as Complete
        from #complete c
       )
     ) t
group by OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm;
```